# How to change default font family in PhpStorm tree files

Tags: angular-material, material-design, phpstorm

Last time I installed `Material theme` for my `PhpStorm`,

then I uninstalled it and my basic font broke down in tree files, it's different than default `PhpStorm`.

I will appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance. There is a checkbox "Use custom font" and a select field.

[image]

Change the font to American Typewriter

[image]

Comment: This changes the font in the entire program except the files tree.

Comment: That is interesting. I updated my answer with another image that shows that the setting effects the tree.

Comment: I was using Material Theme, then i uninstalled it and font is from this pack, can't change this.